# Database Stuck in "Restoring" in SSMS After Running From an Outside Process

Tags: sql-server-2014, stored-procedures, restore, python

I am running a RESTORE DATABASE procedure with RECOVERY and REPLACE from an outside process (Windows Batch using a Python script) and when I do so, it makes my database stuck in "Restoring..." mode every time.  But if I run the procedure manually, it works just fine.  Any thoughts on what might cause this?  I have come up blank in my research [I wasn't sure whether to put this here or the Python community, so I started here].

For example:

Python executes this:

```
exec DB_RESTORE 'MyDatabase','MyDatabase_BACKUP'
```

Which runs this:

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE DB_RESTORE
    @FROMDB VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @TODB VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @FILENAME VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @PATH = 'C:\temp\'
    SET @FILENAME = @PATH + @FROMDB + '_' + 'backup.bak'
    SET @SQL = ''

    SET @SQL ='RESTORE DATABASE ' + @TODB
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM DISK = ''' + @FILENAME + ''''  
    + ' WITH RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS=10'

    PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE(@SQL)
END
GO
```

Comment: Wild guess here, what happens if you remove the `stats=10` and the `print @sql` Maybe your python script isn't processing the output or gets stuck because your procedure is returning something

Comment: Hi Tom V, thanks for the comment.  I will try that, but I am not getting any indication that the Python is hanging as it completes successfully and shows all log printouts [although, that isn't to say there isn't some issue with how it is handling the connection, which is something I'm looking into].

Comment: Does your script output the percent progress and does it end up at a 100?

Comment: It does not and I was going to see if I could get the output from SQL to the Python to see that very thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to give it time so the database restores.

When you run your python code to execute the stored procedure, don't close the connection instantly, but pop a `time.sleep(10)` after it. This will give the database some time to prepare it to the online state (the time you need to sleep will vary based on db size).

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense to me because if it was a synchronous-asynchronous issue, wouldn't it just run the procedure and then be done instantly (connection closes before it finishes backing up)?  That isn't the behavior I was seeing; it seemed to be waiting for some sort of callback from the procedure and was just hanging indefinitely.  If I end up in this situation again though, I'll give it a try.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to solve this directly.  The best I could figure is that it is an issue with the pyodbc driver.  My workaround was to utilize the sqlcmd cli instead of trying to call the stored procedure directly from Python.

Comment: I see you said you had to use sqlcmd in 2018 to get around this but I was wondering if you ran into anything since then as I'm having the exact same issue you describe above.

Comment: @Lumpy Nope.  It worked fine calling the sqlcmd.